# Difference between sign conventions in the action of $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conventions, supersymmetry, action, yang-mills

In the paper called [Wilson Loops in N=4 Supersymmetric Yang-Mills Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0003055), the authors define the action for the $\mathcal{N}=4$ Supersymmetric Yang-Mills (SYM) theory including the following term:

$$S = \frac{1}{2g^2} \int d^4 x \left\lbrace ...-\sum_{i<j} f^{abc} f^{ade} \phi_i^b\phi_j^c\phi_i^d\phi_j^e + ...\right\rbrace\tag{1}$$

The full action is given by eq. (42) in the paper.

However, in another paper called [Two Loops to Two Loops in N=4 Supersymmetric Yang-Mills Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108182), the authors give the following action (eq. (2.3) in the paper):

$$S=\frac{1}{2g^2}\int d^4x \left\lbrace ... + \frac{1}{2} \left(f^{abc} \phi_i^b\phi_j^c\right)^2 + ...\right\rbrace\tag{2}$$

I think that the $1/2$ factor in $(2)$ is the same as having the sum with $i<j$ in $(1)$, but the sign in front of the term is different. In all the other terms of the action, the signs agree in both papers except for this one. Is one of the actions wrong? If not, what is the reason for this discrepancy?

While I am at it, the actions in both papers start with:

$$S = \frac{1}{2g^2} \int d^4x \left\lbrace \frac{1}{2} \left(F_{\mu\nu}^a\right)^2 + ...\right\rbrace\tag{3}$$

Why is there no minus sign, as it is usually the case with YM theories?

Comment: Regarding the + sign in front of the Yang-Mills field strength term, this is because what is written is the Euclidean action. The action in Minkowski space comes with a minus sign.